2 Receivers In the Same Room?
We have a music classroom where we need two teachers to have mics at the same time but a very small budget. We have two wireless microphone receivers of different frequency ranges each plugged in as an input to the back of a speaker. Each teacher has a body pack corresponding to their receiver. Would we risk audio interference from using 2 receivers if they and the packs are on different frequencies?

The different frequencies refers to the radio signal that each microphone transmitter uses. As they are using different frequencies, there will be no problem in that respect.
The potential problem comes from the fact that the receivers both have to produce the same range of audio signals, so, as you appear to suspect, there is a chance of acoustic feedback if one of the teachers is standing too close to a loudspeaker, even if it is the other teacher speaking.
It is best to experiment with two teachers who will actually be using the setup, speaking/singing as loudly as they would to a class. It is possible that there will be no problem.
You probably already know how to reduce the feedback if it happens, as the methods are easily available from a search of the internet; for example: How to Control Feedback in a Sound System.
